# 2 Exchange Servers and IMAP access for external users

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, exchange-2003, port-forwarding, imap

I have two exchange servers for the same domain, so half my mailboxes are on exchangeA and half are on exchangeB

I have opened up IMAP on my firewall, to allow users to make use of their blackberries. So, I forwarded the relevant port from my firewall to ExchangeA, and all is well with the world.

Coincidentally, all the blackberry users are on ExchangeA, and everything worked, until one user, who was on ExchangeB could not get blackberry working, until I realised the reason. I figured then I'd make ExchangeB a front end server, by clicking that little box - I thought that meant it would forward IMAP requests to the correct spot, transparent to the user.

It seems that is not the case. What setup do I need, in order for IMAP to be able to function in this setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the conclusion that I've come to, but I'm pretty sure that an Exchange Front End server is suppose to solve this problem. I'm going to use another of my external IP's and port forward accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you would need to open another port in the firewall, and forward that to IMAP on the second server, and tell your user(s) that they will need to use a different port number.

If their clients don't support configuration of IMAP to a different port, then you need to use a different public IP address, so that you can forward the IMAP port straight.

Comment: This is the conclusion that I've come to, but I'm pretty sure that an Exchange Front End server is suppose to solve this problem.
I'm going to use another of my external IP's and port forward accordingly.